# Show text only in b tags with regex

Tags: python, regex, django, django-queryset

I have QuerySet with output:

```
<b>Author</b> Work
<b>Author</b> Work
<b>Author</b> Work
<b>Author</b> Work
<b>Author</b> Work
```

I want to have an array only with **Autor**.

Below is my code but doesn't works:

```
author_list = self.texts.filter(code='OPEN')
for i in author_list:
    aa = [re.match(r'<b>(.*)</b> ', str(i.text_en))]
return aa
```

Comment: Since I see a couple of possible issues with your code, what do you mean with "doesn't work"? What's the result you're getting?

Comment: And how/why is the queryset returning data like that, rather than model instances?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, it will select all the text between the tag `<b>`

```
author_list = self.texts.filter(code='OPEN')
for i in author_list:
    aa = [re.match(r'<b>(.*?)</b>', str(i.text_en))]
return aa
```